Does including a variable for stepwise change and another variable for linear change in an ARIMAX model introduce issues of multicollinearity?
I am trying to perform interrupted time series analysis using an ARIMA model based on the following paper: Interrupted time series analysis using autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) models: a guide for evaluating large-scale health interventions
One issue I am running into however is whether or not my ARIMA model can include more than one exogenous variable without introducing multicollinearity and inflating the variance of the coefficient estimates. If I run a model with an exogenous variable for S_t (A sudden, sustained change where the time series is shifted either up or down by a given value immediately following the intervention. The step change variable takes the value of 0 prior to the start of the intervention, and 1 afterwards) and R_t (A change in slope that occurs immediately after the intervention. The ramp variable takes the value of 0 prior to the start of the intervention and increases by 1 after the date of the intervention) would that introduce multicollinearity making my results invalid? Should I only run a model with one of these variables at a time?
One way to resolve this that I thought of was to modify R_t (let's call this variable R_t_prime) to increase only after the previous S_t was 1 (ie when S_t is 1 the first time, R_t will be 0, then on the following entry S_t will be 1, and R_t will be 1). Would this remove the relationship between R_t and S_t because S_t can no longer be made via a boolean operation on R_t? Would the model with R_t_prime be more valid because it does not introduce multicollinearity?

Re "without inflating:" the point to introducing a new variable is to improve the model, which usually includes a decrease in the estimation variance of any parameter of interest.  The issue therefore is not whether multicollinearity in itself will degrade the variance, but only whether including the variable is a net improvement.  Moreover, any such "inflation," however you might measure it, does not make your results "invalid."  Thus, your concerns appear premature and perhaps irrelevant. BTW, the two-model approach is no solution and likely to be worse.

To clarify you are asking about whether running a model where the design matrix has two columns which are:



S_t
R_t




0
0


0
0


0
0


0
0


0
0


1
1


1
2


1
3


1
4


1
5


1
6



Would induce colinearity?
I see that this is what is suggested in the paper. Is your proposal to shift R_t by 1 to completely distinguish the ramp  change (time increasing effect) from the sustained change as below:



S_t
R_t_prime




0
0


0
0


0
0


0
0


0
0


1
0


1
1


1
2


1
3


1
4


1
5




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
